How to handle overlapping predictions in multi-step ahead prediction
I have developed an LSTM model and want to examine its performance for different combinations of look-back windows and multiple steps ahead predictions. I'm using the MIMO (Multiple Input, Multiple Output) method for multi-step ahead forecasting. Importantly, I am not using a recursive approach—I only use actual data as inputs rather than feeding predictions back into the model.
Example:
Time series: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], with lookback window equal to 1 and steps ahead equal to 3.
1st iteration: Input: [1], Output: [2, 3, 4]
2nd iteration: Input: [2], Output: [3, 4, 5]
3rd iteration: Input: [3], Output: [4, 5, 6]
4th iteration: Input: [4], Output: [5, 6, 7]

However, this approach results in multiple predictions for certain time steps (e.g., 3, 4, 5, 6).
What I've Tried:
To resolve this, I keep all elements from the first predicted sequence and, for subsequent sequences, I only keep the last element. This way, I only have one prediction per time step, and it seems more appropriate since each step is further out in the prediction horizon.
Question:
Is this approach correct for handling overlapping predictions in the MIMO method? Or is there a better way to handle this overlap in a multi-step ahead prediction setting?
